# Querying a relational table in Django database

Tags: python, django

I have an database with a relational table created by my Models.  This table has all the information I'm trying to query, but I'm having a difficult time getting the values from it that aren't objects of the Model.

`Models.py`

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    '''All ingredients for any recipe or individual selection'''
    ingredient = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ingredient
    
class IngredientDetail(models.Model):
    '''A class to identify variable quantities of ingredients'''
    recipe = models.ForeignKey('Recipe', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    ingredient = models.ForeignKey(Ingredient, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Ingredient Details'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.quantity
    
class Recipe(models.Model):
    '''A Recipe class to input new recipes'''
    recipe = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ingredients = models.ManyToManyField(Ingredient, through=IngredientDetail)
    instructions = models.TextField(null=True)
    cuisine = models.ForeignKey(Cuisine, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'media/', null=True, blank=True)
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.recipe
```

It creates the following table, which has the info I need:

| ID | quantity | ingredient_id | recipe_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 5 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 6 | 5 |
| 3 | 2 | 7 | 5 |

When I try to query Ingredient details with `IngredientDetails.objects.filter(recipe_id='5')`, it only gives me the values for quantity, and I also need the ingredient_id. Did I structure my models incorrectly, or have I overlooked an obvious solution to this?  Ideally, I'd like to be able to write a query for recipe_id, and receive the ingredient_id and quantity associated with it.  Thank you in advance

Comment: It could be that you only see `quantity` because you return it in the `__str__`. Use `IngredientDetails.objects.filter(recipe_id='5').values()` to get a dictionary or just use `object.<field_name>`

Comment: can you please update the question with your usage of the query and the actual result it returns? Based on the model's definition I don't see a reason it will not work